# AndAlso as between statement makes wrong categorization

Tags: vb.net

I have the following function:

```
Public Function GetCategorized(ByVal val As Double) As UInt16
    Dim reVal As UInt16
    If val < 1.0625 Then
        reVal = 0
    ElseIf (1.0625 >= val) AndAlso (val < 1.1) Then
        reVal = 1
    ElseIf (1.1 >= val) AndAlso (val < 1.15) Then
        reVal = 2
    ElseIf (1.15 >= val) AndAlso (val < 1.2) Then
        reVal = 3
    ElseIf (1.2 >= val) AndAlso (val < 1.25) Then
        reVal = 4
    ElseIf (1.25 <= val) Then
        reVal = 5
    End If
    Return reVal
End Function
```

If I put the value `1.10716` into the function I expect to get the value 2 because the value is between 1.1 and 1.15 but instead I get the value 3, could anyone explain, what that is and where I made a mistake, since I just dont see it.

Comment: why would you pass clearly a different type to a function that takes double, that is my first question... and you are doing a comparison against a double and a decimal....

Comment: You have the values switched in the first test in each ElseIf. I think you mean ElseIf (val >= 1.0625) AndAlso (val < 1.1) and so on. In any case, you don't need the first test as it has already been tested for by the earlier If/ElseIf statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the main problem with your code is that you have the val and the number switch round in the first test of each ElseIf. In any case, you can simplify the function like this:

```
Public Function GetCategorized(ByVal val As Double) As UInt16
    If val < 1.0625 Then Return 0
    If Val < 1.1 Then Return 1
    If Val < 1.15 Then Return 2
    If Val < 1.2 Then Return 3
    If Val < 1.25 Then Return 4
    Return 5
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I apply your approach since it is very handy.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to put a value into a bucket like this, I kind of like `Select Case`.  It's got an obvious "pick one of the following" syntax, and it supports the extremely readable `v1 TO v2` range syntax.

```
  Public Function GetCategorized(ByVal val As Double) As UInt16
     Dim reVal As UInt16

     Select Case val
        Case Is >= 1.25
           reVal = 5
        Case 1.2 To 1.25
           reVal = 4
        Case 1.15 To 1.2
           reVal = 3
        Case 1.1 To 1.15
           reVal = 2
        Case 1.05 To 1.1
           reVal = 1
        Case Else
           reVal = 0
     End Select

     Return reVal
  End Function
```

It's not as nice for floating point values as it is for discrete types like integers, because the buckets declared with range syntax have to overlap at their end points (if a bucket has value X as its upper bound, another bucket needs to have X as the lower bound or you'll end up with gaps between buckets).  That means X appears to be in two buckets.  You have to remind yourself that the value gets put into whichever bucket is listed first.  That's why the buckets are listed in reverse order in my example.  It's also a prime opportunity to misread the code on an off day.  For that reason, I don't actually recommend it in this case, but if you're working with discrete values I think it's the way to go.  It would have avoided the mistake that caused the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Is `1.1 >= 1.10716`?

No (it's 0.0716 bigger than 1.1).

Since you're using the short-circuit logical operator, it doesn't evaluate the `val < 1.15` conditional and moves onto the next `ElseIf`. (Even if you weren't using the short-circuit version, the entire condition would still be false.)

In the next `ElseIf`, `1.15 >= 1.10716` is true, additionally `1.10716 < 1.2` is also true, so the entire condition evaluates to true and `3` is returned.

Comment: ah ok! Thanks. I had to change >= to <=.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different to the other answers. I would also suggest you set meaningful variable names. Learn to debug and step through the code, you would've notice that was happening pretty quickly.

```
Public Function GetCategorized(ByVal val As Double) As UInt16

    Dim category As UInt16

    If val < 1.0625 Then
        category = 0
    ElseIf val < 1.1 Then
        category = 1
    ElseIf val < 1.15 Then
        category = 2
    ElseIf val < 1.2 Then
        category = 3
    ElseIf val < 1.25 Then
        category = 4
    Else
        category = 5
    End If

    Return category
End Function
```